# Random Number array in Java - want to sort ascending

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am creating random number generator in Java as part of program I am writing to learn the language better (come from more C#/C++ background).

```
    ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Random ran = new Random();
    for(int i = 1; i <= 11; i++)
        al.add(i);


    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int num = al.remove(ran.nextInt(al.size()));

        temp.add(num);
        Arrays.sort(temp);

        text("\Random Number " + i + " is: " + temp[i]);
    }
```

On arrays.sort(temp) I get a no suitable method error and in my text output function I get array required but java.util.ArrayList found.  Can anyone suggest a better way to sort this random number array into ascending order or see something I am doing wrong currently that could easily be corrected?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Collections.sort(temp)`.

In Java, arrays and lists are two different beasts. [`Arrays.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) only works for arrays; the equivalent function for lists is [`Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29).

I can't say I fully understand the logic behind your code, but you might also want to take a look at [`Collections.shuffle()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Random%29).

**edit** Upon closer inspection, there are other problems with the code:

1. You are re-creating `temp` from scratch, so on each loop iteration it will contain exactly one element.
2. `temp[i]` is not valid syntactically; the correct syntax is `temp.get(i)`. Even with the correct syntax, it'll give you an "out of bounds" exception, since `temp` only contains one element.

Comment: Many Thanks - thats what you get when you search array sort in Java on google first. :)  I will also take a look at collections.shuffle.  With regards the output line after changing to Collections.Sort(temp);  can i still print out the line with the temp[i] index?

Comment: @KOL: The correct syntax is `temp.get(i)`. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

When sorting a ArrayList you should use:

```
Collections.sort();
```

In your case, I suggest you to use a [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), it provides you a sorted collection (it sort itself after every add or remove. Also, it prevents you from adding duplicate elements.

```
TreeSet<Integer> randomSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();
Random ran = new Random();
while(randomSet.size() < 3) {   
    randomSet.add(Math.abs(ran.nextInt()) % 11 + 1); //+1 to adjust your range [1..11]
}

for (int i : randomSet)
    System.out.println(i);
```

Math.abs() guarantee that you will only have positive numbers and you can use % operator to set a maximum value.

More info on add took from oracle docs:

> If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set unchanged and returns false.

Comment: Thanks for this extra logic.  I want 2 random numbers generated in the range 1-11.  So from your comment the % should have 11 after it and the for loop <=3 so generate 3 numbers?  The only other contraint I have is that I dont want duplictae random numbers (i.e - if 3 comes out the next time round it should not be selected.

Comment: That was very useful - thanks - can you explain a bit more on how the % 11 + 1 is working - i.e why the need to add +1 and if I was my range was 20 I would not need the + 1 right?  Is it the same as the modulo operator in C++?  thanks

Comment: Yes, that's the same in C++. Without the +1, the range goes from 0 to 10. The +1 is just a kludge to adjust your range to 1 to 11

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Collection` class for sort the `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<Integer> al =new ArrayList<Integer>();

Collections.sort(al , new Comparator<Integer>()
{
  public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
    return a.compareTo(b) ;
  }
});
```

So now the `al` has a sorted list.

Answer (score 0):

It will do:

```
Collections.sort();
```